# Show that two sets are countable infinite

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to solve the following problem and I was hoping some of you could give me some hints on how to procede.

> Show that for all $w\in \mathbb{C}$ the sets
>   $$
> \{z \in \mathbb{C}: \sin(z) = w\}
> \quad\text{and}\quad
> \{z \in \mathbb{C} : \cos(z) = w\}
> $$
>
> are countable infinite.

I think that I have to find a bijection between the given sets and $\mathbb{N}$ but I don't really see how. 
Any hint (or solution) will be really appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Consider how many solutions can those equations have in each of the compact discs $\{|z|\leq n\}$. Could $\sin$ or $\cos$ be equal to $w$ infinitely many times inside a compact?

Comment: You don't have to explicitly find a bijection. You can just show that if one of these sets is uncountable, then something that doesn't happen, should happen. Then derive a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You can use the Identity Theorem to prove that there are only finitely many such $z$ inside an open disc of any radius. It's a set theoretical exercise to show that the countable union of finite sets is countable. Therefore, your result will follow from the fact that $\mathbb{C}$ is the union of countably many open discs.

Comment: Ok. I know that $sin(z)$ and $cos(z)$ are holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}$ so if I define $G:= \{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| < n\}$ we can apply the Identity Theorem to say that if $sin(z) = w \forall z \in G$ then $sin(z) = w$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$ and similarly for $cos(z)$ right? I'm sorry but I don't see how to say that then the set $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : sin (z) = w\}$ is countable infinite.

Comment: I edited my answer to make it slightly more apparent. The key set theoretical argument is that you can show a set is countable infinite by showing that it is the union of countably many finite sets.

If this is for a complex analysis class I'm guessing that your professor assumes that step is clear, and most of the work will be in justifying the use of the identity theorem. Make sure you give a more detailed explanation of why the identity theorem can be applied when you write your homework.